# Stackblitz development server is not working

Tags: stackblitz

Its been week, stackblitz dev server is not running on using angular material.I have tried opening server in same tab as well.

Answer (score 0):

Stop and start for me too (on ios/ipad with material).

I managed to fix this by removing unneccessary material modules.